# Cannot find module '@nestjs/passport' or its corresponding type declarations.?

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, passport.js, pnpm

well,I can't use jwt and its methods because when I use docker-compose up and it compiles, my modules are not being found, I've already downloaded the types, I've already downloaded node again and I've also restarted docker,I already deleted the dist folder, but nothing.

my strategy:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt'
import { JwtRequisicao } from './jwtSignRe';
@Injectable()
export class JwtRetira extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
        jwtDaRequisicao: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
            (request: JwtRequisicao) => {
                return request?.jwt
            }
        ]),
        ignoreExpiration: false,
        secretOrkey: process.env.JWT_SEGREDO
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { ...payload}
  }
}
```

idk if this is causing by the strategy, but i add this too, when docker try to compile, appear 3 errors:

1 one:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/passport' or its corresponding type declarations.
(import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';)
```

2 one:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'passport-jwt' or its corresponding type declarations.
(import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt')
```

3: one:

```
rror TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/passport' or its corresponding type declarations.
(import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';)
```

Dockerfile(is the same to both app's)

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    env_file:
      - .env

  auth:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app 
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev auth 
  namatus:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/namatus/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '4000:5000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - auth
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app 
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev namatus

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  postgres_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '15432:80'
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "namatus",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"apps/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/apps/namatus/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./apps/namatus/test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm --dataSource ./dist/apps/auth/apps/auth/src/db/data-source-cli.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.2.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.3.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.3.3",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.5",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.3.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.3.3",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^5.1.2",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.38",
    "amqp-connection-manager": "^4.1.14",
    "amqplib": "^0.10.3",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.4",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.14.15",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20",
    "uninstall": "^0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.3.2",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.1.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.3.3",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.5",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.19",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "cache-manager": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/libs/",
      "<rootDir>/apps/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@app/livraria(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/libs/livraria/src/$1"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what's causing this, whether it's the node version's fault, or some kind of bug?

Comment: someone can help with this problem?

Comment: this happens too to cacher-manager and @nestjs/throttler, what I need to do?

Comment: Seems like a `node_modules` folder is missing values. Can you provide your `Dockerfile` and `package.json`(s)`?

Comment: Does your Dockerfile reference replace the contents of the application's `node_modules:` directory with a volume mount?  That will ignore any changes to your `package.json` file.  Try deleting a Compose `volumes:` block for the application if you have one.

Comment: i will add both compose and Dockerfile

Comment: I edited and added, package.json too,  Can you take a look, see where I went wrong, and also explain it to me, so I understand so I don't make the same mistake next time.